# Grey screen of design on android studio with coordinator layout written.

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8XTs.jpg)

[Here is the design screen on android studio. You can understand what is my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJuXM.jpg)

Comment: always post code as text not as image

Comment: click on the info icon in the layout editor and tell what is the error

Answer (score 0):

Change target sdk to 27 in build.gradle. This may work.